# Search & Display Info from Parallel Array

Tags: java, arrays

just another newbie here needing help with a coding dilemma. The program I'm trying to create is a small database that has to use three parallel arrays (userNumber, player, and highScore). The intention is that the user should enter the a user number at the prompt and the program will display the person's information. If the number entered doesn't exist then the program should show them the number they entered and make them re-enter a user number until a correct one is entered.
The problems I'm running into now is that the program doesn't accept any user number except the first user number in the array, whether or not it's a valid number in the array list. Also, the error message only displays the first "incorrect" number regardless of how many times a "wrong" number is entered.
In short, I guess the right questions would be:
1.) Exactly what should I change in order for the program to return the info for just the array entries that correspond to the entered userNumber?
2.) What do I change to make each error message display the "incorrect" number that was just entered?
Here's the code I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HighScoreSearch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] userNumber = new int[5];
        String[] player = new String[5];
        Double[] highScore = new Double[5];

        userNumber[0]= 1;
        userNumber[1]= 2;
        userNumber[2]= 3;
        userNumber[3]= 4;
        userNumber[4]= 5;
        player[0]= "Morpheus";
        player[1]= "Neo";
        player[2]= "Cereal Killer";
        player[3]= "Crash Override";
        player[4]= "Acid Burn";
        highScore[0]= 853797.67;
        highScore[1]= 999999.99;
        highScore[2]= 15097.34;
        highScore[3]= 864513.16;
        highScore[4]= 543188.68;

        System.out.print("Enter User# ");
        int scan= input.nextInt();
        int i=0;

        while (scan!=userNumber[i])
        {
            System.out.printf("Error #%s Is Unknown User", scan);
            System.out.print("Enter User# ");
            scan=input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.printf("%s, user# %s, has a high score of: %s", player[i], userNumber[i], highScore[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: so this code `while (scan!=userNumber[i])` is equivalent to `while (scan != 1)`

Comment: You never actually look for the input user number in your **ENTIRE** array `userNumber`

Comment: BTW this question has nothing to do with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the entered value - consider

```
        while (scan < userNumber[0] || scan > userNumber[4])
        {
            System.out.printf("Error #%s Is Unknown User", scan);
            System.out.print("Enter User# ");
            scan=input.nextInt();
        }
        // now use the value
        System.out.printf("%s, user# %s, has a high score of: %s",
                    player[scan-1], userNumber[scan-1], highScore[scan-1]);
```

Of course, you should really `loop` through the `userNumber` array to check if the number is there.  In reality such a solution would require you to create single obejcts holding this information and then having a `List` or `array` of these objects

Comment: You get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if user entered player #5

Comment: @KevinAnderson and the wrong record even if he didn't - fixed it now

Comment: This assumes that the user numbers are in order.

Comment: This definitely helped work out some of the problems, but has left me with some additional issues. I need to be able to use the program even if the "userNumber" is not just in order from 1-to-5.  Any simple ideas if the numbers are anywhere from 1-to-9999?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a HashMap for your users instead of an array. Otherwise, you would have to loop through the entire array each time to find if the user exists.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> userMap = new HashMap<>();

// map user numbers to associative array indexes.
userMap.put(1, 0);
userMap.put(2, 1);
userMap.put(3, 2);
userMap.put(4, 3);
userMap.put(5, 4);

player[0]= "Morpheus";
player[1]= "Neo";
player[2]= "Cereal Killer";
player[3]= "Crash Override";
player[4]= "Acid Burn";
highScore[0]= 853797.67;
highScore[1]= 999999.99;
highScore[2]= 15097.34;
highScore[3]= 864513.16;
highScore[4]= 543188.68;

System.out.print("Enter User# ");
int scan= input.nextInt();

// loop until the user actually exists
while (!userMap.containsKey(scan))
{
    System.out.printf("Error #%s Is Unknown User", scan);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter User# ");
    scan=input.nextInt();

}

// get the index for the user
int lookup = userMap.get(scan);

System.out.printf("%s, user# %s, has a high score of: %s", player[lookup], scan, highScore[lookup]);
```

**Note**
The other benefit with using this approach is that your user numbers don't have to be in order.

For example, you can have the following mapping and the code would still work:

```
userMap.put(1, 0);
userMap.put(2, 1);
userMap.put(9, 2); // user # 9 can map to index 2.
userMap.put(4, 3);
userMap.put(5, 4);
```

Per @ScaryWombat it would be ideal to create a Player class so you don't have to use associative arrays and make your program more OO.

**Example**:

```
class Player
{
   private int id = 0;
   private String name;
   private Double score = 0.0;

   public Player (int id, String name, double score)
   {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.score = score;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return String.format("%s, user# %s, has a high score of: %s", name, id, score);
   }
}
```

Then, you can create a HashMap of Integer to Player

```
Map<Integer, Player> userMap = new HashMap<>();

userMap.put(1, new Player(1, "Morpheus", 853797.67));
userMap.put(2, new Player(2, "Neo", 999999.99));
userMap.put(3, new Player(3, "Cereal Killer", 15097.34));
userMap.put(4, new Player(4, "Crash Override", 864513.16));
userMap.put(5, new Player(5, "Acid Burn", 543188.68));
```

Now, you can look up the Player like this:

```
// get the player object for the user id
Player p = userMap.get(scan);

// print out the player like this since it has a toString()
System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Not the DV'er but something like `Map<Integer, Player> userMap = new HashMap<>();` would be more realistic

Comment: @ScaryWombat - true, but I'm trying to make the changes are simple as possible w/o adding to much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm proving another answer that uses arrays, since your requirement is to use parallel arrays. Please see all the comments in the code. I've added error checking so the program doesn't exit nor get into an invalid state.

The key here is that you have to loop through the entire array each time the user enters a potential user number.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HighScoreSearch
{
    // You need an indicator for an invalid user in the case where
    // you don't use all array positions
    private static final int INVALID_USER_NUM = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // consider renaming this int to something like userNumber (scan is not very meaningful)
        int scan = 0;

        int[] userNumber = new int[10];
        String[] player = new String[10];
        Double[] highScore = new Double[10];

        userNumber[0]= 10;
        userNumber[1]= 777;
        userNumber[2]= 5;
        userNumber[3]= 1234;
        userNumber[4]= 357;

        // set the rest to an invalid user #; otherwise these will have a value 0 by default
        userNumber[5]= INVALID_USER_NUM;
        userNumber[6]= INVALID_USER_NUM;
        userNumber[7]= INVALID_USER_NUM;
        userNumber[8]= INVALID_USER_NUM;
        userNumber[9]= INVALID_USER_NUM;

        player[0]= "Morpheus";
        player[1]= "Neo";
        player[2]= "Cereal Killer";
        player[3]= "Crash Override";
        player[4]= "Acid Burn";

        highScore[0]= 853797.67;
        highScore[1]= 999999.99;
        highScore[2]= 15097.34;
        highScore[3]= 864513.16;
        highScore[4]= 543188.68;

        // this represents the array index of the user across the arrays
        int indexOfUser = 0;

        // flag to indicate if we found a valid user
        boolean userFound = false;
        do
        {
            String replyBox = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User#");

            // consider trimming this replyBox value
            // If they enter "10  " (w/o quotes would you still want that to be valid)
            replyBox = replyBox.trim();

            scan = INVALID_USER_NUM; // default to an invalid user #
            try
            {
                scan = Integer.parseInt(replyBox);
            }
            catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                // they didn't enter a valid integer, but you don't want to exit the program
            }

            // don't bother searching if it's invalid
            if (scan != INVALID_USER_NUM)
            {
                // loop through each user to see if you find the entered #
                for (int i = 0; i < userNumber.length && !userFound; i++)
                {
                    // we found this user
                    if (scan == userNumber[i])
                    {
                        indexOfUser = i;
                        userFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!userFound)
            {
                // you should use replyBox instead of scan here
                //String messagefalse = String.format("Error %s is an Unknown User", scan);
                String messagefalse = String.format("Error: '%s' is an Unknown User", replyBox);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messagefalse);
            }

        } while (!userFound); // loop until we find a user

        // we've found a user - use the indexOfUser to index the arrays
        String messagetrue = String.format("%s, user# %s, has a high score of: %s", player[indexOfUser], userNumber[indexOfUser], highScore[indexOfUser]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messagetrue);
    }
}
```